# Update variable in JS based on selected option from dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this dropdown, where I want to change the variable in my js script based on which option is selected. The variable is send to another function which updates the page.

My html file:

```js
//My JS function that is trying to access the data from the dropdown

    function updateDD(){
        $(".sheetnameSelect").change(function(){
            return $(this).find(":selected").text()
        }) 
    }

//I want to use that function to update another variable based on selected option

    var selected = updateDD()
    alert(selected)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class='sheetnameSelect'>
            <option value="Cars">Cars</option>
            <option value="Homes">Homes</option>
            <option value="Planes">Planes</option>
    </select>
```

However the function `updateDD()` is not returning the selected option (both when the pages loads or when I select different option)

Comment: You can't return anything from an event handler; treat them as asynchronous logic. As such the pattern you're trying to follow is flawed. Instead of updating a variable when the `select` itself changes, read the value of the `select` when needed by another action, eg. on click of a submit button.

Comment: Is it possible to read the value of selected without explicit action? Selecting different dropdown option would be the only action required by the user.

Comment: Yes, just run the logic on page load. If you need a specific example of how to do this then we would need to see more of your use case to understand the context you're working in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might not need to return the value, you can call the method whenever there is a change in `select`:

```js
$(".sheetnameSelect").on('change', function() {
  var selected = $(this).val();
  createTable(selected);
});

function createTable(value) {
  console.log(value);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class='sheetnameSelect'>
  <option value="Cars">Cars</option>
  <option value="Homes">Homes</option>
  <option value="Planes">Planes</option>
</select>
```